# How to override the URL-based component name for Application Insights telemetry?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I want to override my web API's component name shown in the Application Insights transaction search.

[image]

I am already setting the cloud role name, which has previously worked well, and even now works for some of the telemetry, as indicated by the single green marking on the image. However, almost all telemetry seems to ignore the cloud role name and instead uses the URL host as the component name, indicated by the three red marks on the image. Is it possible to override this?

I can confirm that all the raw JSON telemetry data sent to AI has `ai.cloud.role` set to the correct value. Furthermore, I find no traces of the host in the raw telemetry data that is sent, other than in the URL of course. This makes me believe that the component name is set directly by Azure Portal and is not possible to override. This assumption is supported by the fact that the single telemetry item on the image with the correct component name represents a call to my component from Azure Service Bus, i.e. not a HTTP call.

Comment: How do you set cloud role name? What is component name? Is it a name of your Application Insights resource?

Comment: The cloud role name is set via an `ITelemetryInitializer`. It is working fine in itself; it's what you see marked in green on the screenshot (the name `VBIT.Authentication` is not available anywhere else, only in the cloud role name, so it must work). I'm unsure what you mean by "what is component name"; as I mentioned, the name marked in red on the screenshot is the host component of the URL of the API (Azure App Service / Web App). The value marked in red is AFAIK not available anywhere else, so it must be taken from the App Service URL.

Comment: Double checking - *vbit.com - this is the URL of web app, not Application Insights resource name, correct? Context - UI has a logic to use Application Insights resource name if cloud role name is not provided. So, if this is not Application Insights resource name, then this is coming somehow from your app. Let's confirm and then we'll try to understand where it is coming from.

Comment: Correct. My app code/config does not explicitly contain the `observation.devapi.vbit.com` value anywhere; that can only come from two places: 1) the custom domain I have added to the App Service, and 2) the actual URL the call was made to. I just experimented and found that #2 is (at least partly) correct: When the API is called with its custom `observation.devapi.vbit.com` domain, the component name is `observation.devapi.vbit.com` as shown above. When it is called with its default domain, `my-app-service-name.azurewebsites.com`, its AI component name is `my-app-service-name`.

Comment: What type of telemetry is it? Trace/Request/Dependency?

Comment: Yes, all three.